# Add space before date in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What's the formula for adding a space before a date in a cell?
Eg, [space]25/12/1999

Comment: Do you want the cell formatted with a space or do you want a text formula that starts with a space?

Comment: Whichever, as long as I end up with a space before the date in one cell

Comment: Then set the format of the cell to Custom with ` dd/mm/yyyy` as the format - or more explicitly to `" "dd/mm/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as to what you want:

> Under presumption your first date is stored in A1, then B1 would be

`=" " & Text(A1, "DD/MM/YYYY")`

Be careful what you wish for though, this converts the dates to text. What I think what you should want to do instead of artificially adding space before date is to indent the cell instead.

This is done through formatting.

1. Select cell(s) you want to apply the indent to
2. Right Click -> Format Cells
3. Alignment Tab
4. Indent 1 *(or whatever value you desire)*

[image]

Comment: `=" " & Text(A1, "DD/MM/YYYY")` otherwise you'll end up something funky like `" 43512"

Comment: "this converts the dates to text" - no it doesn't.

Comment: @B.1988 That's good info. I think your question is best answered by changing the cell Format (right click>>Format) to a Custom format that preserves your date, but adds the space. Even the `Text()` version I posted will end up storing as text, but will look like a "date".

Comment: @JNevill good point, edited accordingly. I also included indenting in my answer, which seems like something OP is trying to artificially achieve anyways

Comment: @Rawrplus - Indenting adds whitespace but that's not necessarily the same as a space.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am aware. As I pointed out in my comment, >"seems like something OP is artificially trying to achieve indenting with the space" If in fact he really insists on adding a space, then he couldjust refer to JNevill's answer which is pretty elegant in itself

Comment: The indenting didn't work for what I'm trying to achieve, however the formula did. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A cell formula will add a space but will change the cell to "Text" instead "Date" for storage which might not be desirable (but may fit your needs just fine). Instead though you can use *Cell Formatting*.

Right-click the cell and choose "Format"

Go to "Custom" in the list of formatting options and enter " DD/MM/YYYY" in the box (without the double quotes, note the space before the letters.

[image]

The nice thing about this option, besides preservation of the date as a "date" format, is that this copies and pastes from the clipboard with the space preserved (if you copy/paste into notepad for instance).

Comment: It is permissible to put the space inside double-quotes to make it clear that it starts with a space.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity I didn't know that you could use double quotes in there. That is much clearer.

Comment: The double-quotes are like an escape. It lets you put characters in that would otherwise mean something - like starting all dates with a `"d"`.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. I guess I've never had the need to stick a string literal in the format before, which is strange considering how many times I've monkeyed with format in the past.